# regex matches when the whole line is correct

Tags: regex, pcre

Let's bring an example:

```
Go and drink in the FooBar
It's a very nicö place
John Skeet is the bartender
```

My goal is to select the whole line only if ALL CHAR matches the regex. Here for instance I want to select only the lines without an umlaut: `[a-zA-Z\ \']+`

Now I've found a way to select the whole line with `^$` but I wasn't very successful on regex101 with it.

How can I select the whole line when all char's in the line matches with the regex?

Comment: What is the trouble? Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/eBbeCb/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sometimes I feel stupider than I ever expected to be..

Comment: You should just specify the multiline flag. However, the best way is just to read a file line by line, you would just use `/^[a-zA-Z ']+$/` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have a multiline string and you want to match valid lines, you need to enclose the pattern with `^` and `$` anchors, and redefine their behavior by adding a multiline modifier:

```
/^[a-zA-Z ']+$/m
```

or

```
/^[a-z ']+$/im
```

If you handle a file, you may read file line by line and avoid the multiline modifier.